# Finding limit for given function

Tags: limits

> If $f(x)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{n} \left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-x/n}}+\frac{1}{1+e^{-2x/n}}+\dots+\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} \right)$
>   then what is  $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{2f(x)-x}{x^2}\right)$?

My solution is :

$f(x)=0$ since $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{n}$ part will be zero for $n=\infty$, making entire term $0$.

then $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{2f(x)-x}{x^2}\right)$ will become $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{-x}{x^2}\right)$ or $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{-1}{x}\right)$ = $\infty$.

This answer is not avaiable in the given options. What should be the correct answer for this questions?

Comment: Hello, did you copy the expression of $f$ correctly? You used some $\cdots$ but I don't understand what should be inside the parenthesis when you write $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{n}\left(\frac1{1 + e^{-x/n}} + \frac1{1 + e^{-2x/n}} + \cdots + \frac1{1 + e^{-x}} \right)$

Comment: Do you mean that the exponents of $e$ are from $-x/n$ up until $-nx/n$?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is not correct because $f$ is not identically zero.
Note that the definition of $f$ is the limit of a Riemann sum:
$$\begin{align}f(x)&=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{n} \left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-x/n}}+\frac{1}{1+e^{-2x/n}}+\dots+\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} \right)\\&=x\int_0^1\frac{dt}{1+e^{-tx}}=\ln\left(\frac{e^x+1}{2}\right).\end{align}$$
Therefore, as $x\to 0$,
$$\begin{align}
2f(x)-x&=2\ln\left(\frac{1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)+1}{2}\right)-x\\
&=2\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{4}+o(x^2)\right)-x\\
&=2\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^2}{8}+o(x^2)\right)-x
=\frac{x^2}{4}+o(x^2)
\end{align}$$
and we may conclude that the given limit is $1/4$.